# docker exec interactive bash with init commands

Tags: bash, docker

For debugging I'd like to jump into any docker container I have and set a few niceties on my interactive bash shell off the bat. For some reason the --init-file style below is now working.

As with many things I imagine it's some escape sequence issue of sorts I'm missing. Any suggestions?

```
docker exec -it mycontainer bash --init-file <(echo "PS1='\w\$ '; TERM=xterm256; alias ls='ls -GFh'")
```

None of the commands in --init-file are applied to the bash shell launched in the container.

Comment: None of the commands in --init-file are applied to the bash shell launched in the container.

Comment: And why you don't want to pass them as env variables? Something like ```docker exec -it -e PS1='\w\$ ' -e TERM=xterm256 mycontainer bash ``` ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue. Want to automatically source a virtualenv before shelling in.

Comment: This doesn't work because the path generated by the `<()` expression only exists on the host, and not inside the container.  The command executed will be something like `bash /proc/self/fd/11`, and that file won't exist inside the container because it has a different `/proc`

Answer (score 1):

Given your bash configuration in the file `my-bash-niceties`

> #my-bash-niceties
>   PS1='\w\$ '
>   TERM=xterm256
>   alias ll='ls -GFh'

### Option 1

One possibility is to mount the bash configuration file in your container...

```sh
docker run --detach -it -v `pwd`/my-bash-niceties:/etc/bashrc --name mycontainer bash:4.0
```

... and call bash using it as the init file.

```sh
docker exec -it  mycontainer bash  --init-file /etc/bashrc
```

### Option 2

Another option is to mount your bash config file as your `~/.bashrc` ...

```sh
docker run --detach -it -v `pwd`/my-bash-niceties:/root/.bashrc --name mycontainer bash:4.0
```

... and just exec bash in the container.

```
docker exec -it  mycontainer bash
```

In theory, the third (and best!) option, is just to mount the bash config file as /etc/profile.d/my_bash_rc.sh (any .sh file works), but I don't know why this container does not honor this convention. :(

btw, the option --init-file refers to a file **inside** the container's filesystem.